# How we can create a horizontal listview without using a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, android-listview

```
 ListView listview = new ListView(context);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout_190 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        listview.setLayoutParams(layout_190);
        listview.setAdapter(adapterViewAndroid);
        relativeLayout_716.addView(listview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use listView to show items horizontally ,you should use recyclerView or custom listView in [github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView)